# WOPI Implementation for files - on-prem

Tags: ms-wopi

I have a website hosted on-prem which uses Solr to search and index documents from various systems like SMB, Box, Windows File Share, etc. I would like to enable a preview for these documents indexed. Can I utilize the Microsoft Office Online Server for this? What are the additional steps I should perform?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

1. [Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server) Office Online Server. For preview purposes, you can leave the server in the read-only mode (without the `-EditingEnabled` option)
2. Implement [`CheckFileInfo`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#checkfileinfo)
3. Implement [`GetFile`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/GetFile.html#getfile)

There are [boilerplates](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost) out there that can help save you time implementing the WOPI protocol and let you focus on implementing an interface to your specific datastore (be it SMB, Windows File Share, etc.)